custom fonts for wordpress ,not show in customizer
i tried to add custom fonts to my wordpress theme
i buy this theme from foresttheme
i added my codes to the theme and then i can see my fonts in elementor
but in customizer of wordpress , in tpography section,  i can't see my fonts
i dont know why , the elementor can use fonts but in customizer i cant see them.
in another wordpress theme i added my fonts with this code in function
function my_custom_font_family( $fonts ) {
$fonts['Yekan_Bakh'] = array( 'normal' );
   

    return $fonts;

  }
  add_filter( 'csf_field_typography_customwebfonts', 'my_custom_font_family' );
}

